# Regular Expression to extract only a word

Tags: python, regex

I have a complex File like this:

> "start_nm":"BOSTON","bus_num":"1", "bus_num":"2","dest_nm":"NEW YorK"

I want to get `Boston,1,2,newyork`.
The issue is: some cities have `1,2,3,5` and some have `1,2`.
1) Instead of not having multiple if statements how can I get them in a simple statement?
2) As the number of `bus_num` is dynamic how can I keep the loop?

```
match1 = re.search('start_nm\":\"([^"]*)', line)
    if match1:
        print ("The start is  :"+match1.group(1))
match2= re.search('bus_num\":\"(\d+)', line)
    if match1:
        print ("The start is  :"+match1.group(1))
```

I am able to extract them but looking for a simple way to: 
1) Other than this big if the condition for all the statements of any packages.
2) When the length is dynamic for `bus_num` how can I have the loop?

Comment: [Change](https://ideone.com/bNRSho) `(\S*)` to `([^"]*)`.

Comment: Thank you that worked. but is there a better package for these things other than what I am doing?

Comment: If it is JSON, use `json` module.

Comment: This is not json this is a Textfile. I have conditions like this around 20. so I am writing a if else else.....looking for some thing better

Comment: Can you guarantee that there are no commas inside a text field? That would make the problem much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to look for everything between `:"` and the next `"`, like this:

```
>>> line = '>   "start_nm":"BOSTON","bus_num":"1", "bus_num":"2","dest_nm":"NEW YorK"'
>>> re.findall(r':"(.*?)"', line)
['BOSTON', '1', '2', 'NEW YorK']
```

Answer (score 0):

This format looks extremely similar to JSON. One solution:

```
>>> line = '"start_nm":"BOSTON","bus_num":"1", "bus_num":"2","dest_nm":"NEW YorK"'
>>> json.loads(f"{{ {line} }}").values()
dict_values(['BOSTON', '2', 'NEW YorK'])
```

Note the duplicate key "bus_num" which is preventing this solution from fully working

Another solutions:

```
>>> line = '"start_nm":"BOSTON","bus_num":"1", "bus_num":"2","dest_nm":"NEW YorK"'
>>> [v.split(",")[0][1:-1] for v in line.split(":")[1:]]
['BOSTON', '1', '2', 'NEW YorK']
```

Comment: I want use json approach is there a way we can include both the bus_numbers

Comment: @MLLearner2 Yes, either do `"bus_num": [1,2]` or `"bus_num1": 1, "bus_num2": 2`. Also, you'll want to enclose each line with `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that creates a dictionary from your string
*(intentionally avoided using comprehensions, etc. to keep it  simple)*:

```
line = '"start_nm":"BOSTON","bus_num":"1", "bus_num":"2","dest_nm":"NEW YorK"'
line = (line.replace('\"','')).split(',')
d = {}
for l in line:
    k = l.strip().split(':')[0]
    v = l.strip().split(':')[1]
    if k in d:
        d[k] += ' ' + v
    else:
        d[k] = v

print(d)
print(d['start_nm'], '\t', d['bus_num'], '\t', d['dest_nm'])  

## {'start_nm': 'BOSTON', 'bus_num': '1 2', 'dest_nm': 'NEW YorK'}
## BOSTON    1 2     NEW YorK
```